# Extract nodeList item ids as an array with array map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to save a set of ids based on a nodeList returned by a querySelector.

I achieved it with a very procedural approach, thinking in terms of steps.

1. Select items
2. Create an array
3. Iterate over items
4. Get the id
5. Push it into the array

```js
const getThem = document.querySelectorAll('.get-me');

let arrayOfData = [];

Array.prototype.forEach.call (getThem, function (node){
    arrayOfData.push(node.id);
});

console.log(arrayOfData);
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="get-me" id="one">One</li>
<li class="get-me" id="two">Two</li>
<li class="get-me" id="three">Three</li>
</ul>
```

I wonder if I can get this done with array map, to reduce the amount of lines and also take advantage of modern Javascript features.

I tried with:

```
const getThem = document.querySelectorAll('.get-me');
Array.prototype.map.call(getThem, (item) => ({ [id]: item.id }));
console.log(getThem);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `NodeList`s don't have a `.map(..)` function but you can convert it to an array pretty easily, something like `[...getThem]`. Here is a complete example: `[...getThem].map((node) => node.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that is returned by `.querySelectorAll()` [doesn't have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#instance_methods) a `.map()` method. However, as it is [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), you can pass it to [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), and use the second mapping argument to perform your mapping:

```js
const getThem = document.querySelectorAll('.get-me');
const arrayOfData = Array.from(getThem, node => node.id);
console.log(arrayOfData);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="get-me" id="one">One</li>
  <li class="get-me" id="two">Two</li>
  <li class="get-me" id="three">Three</li>
</ul>
```

This does two things in one go, it converts your NodeList to an array, and it performs the mapping based on the second argument. This is opposed to doing something like `Array.from(getThem).map(...)` and `[...getThem].map(...)` which both do two iterations over your items.

---

> I tried with:
>
> ```
> const getThem =
> document.querySelectorAll('.get-me');
> Array.prototype.map.call(getThem, (item) => ({ [id]: item.id }));
> console.log(getThem);
> ```
>
> But it doesn't work.

This does also work, you just need to store the return value in a variable a log that. `.map()` doesn't change the original array, it returns a new one instead:

```js
const getThem = document.querySelectorAll('.get-me');
const res = Array.prototype.map.call(getThem, (item) => item.id);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="get-me" id="one">One</li>
  <li class="get-me" id="two">Two</li>
  <li class="get-me" id="three">Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it using `spread operator` and `array map` like below

```js
const getThem = document.querySelectorAll('.get-me');
const nodes = [...getThem];

const arrayOfData = nodes.map(node => node.id);

console.log(arrayOfData);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="get-me" id="one">One</li>
  <li class="get-me" id="two">Two</li>
  <li class="get-me" id="three">Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it. I'll accept the other answer because it was first. But the real accepted answer should be both combined. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.get-me')
const arrayOfData = Array.from(elems).map(({ id }) => id)

console.log(arrayOfData)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="get-me" id="one">One</li>
  <li class="get-me" id="two">Two</li>
  <li class="get-me" id="three">Three</li>
</ul>
```